# C# turn decimals for money into integers

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an (`C# .NET Core` / `SQL Express`) application that is very critical with money calculations. I've read a lot of blog and posts saying that `float` is not precise enough for storing critical things like money values. So I used `decimal`.

But now when I'm digging deeper in it, it seems to be the best idea to store everything as `integer` and just use the cent value instead of the decimal value for money. So instead of storing a value as € `1.99`. I store it as `199`.

**My first question**: Is this really a better and safer approach?

**Secondly**, I have already a complete application using `Entity Framework` that is based on decimal values in every function that uses prices.
I thought, as only storing the values in the database might be the problem, to use the getter and setter of the variable to convert it to and back from integers.

So for example:

```
public class InvoiceDomain
{
   public decimal Total {get;set;}
}
```

becomes this:

```
public class InvoiceDomain
{
   public int totalCents

   [NotMapped]
   public decimal Total 
   { 
          get { return totalCents / 100; } 
          set { totalCents = (int)value * 100; } 
   }
}
```

Is that a good idea to do?

Comment: You will also need to store the _exponent_ value... you just cannot hard-code 100.

Comment: You are correct that float in sql server is not precise. But the decimal datatype is precise. I would use a decimal instead of all this converting back and forth all the time. What you are doing is storing an implied decimal. It works but forces you to constantly convert your value to see what it really is. Stick with decimal and save yourself a lot of hassle.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks a lot! I was doubting about all those blogs and articles over the internet.

Comment: Yes, it used to be a good practice in time of old (when we didn't have anything like `decimal` but `double` only). Now you can use, say, `Number(15, 2)` for euro on RDMS side and `decimal` on the client

Comment: How many decimals are you going to use? Different currencies have a different number of decimals and rules that govern rounding and conversions. Using an integer is *not* a good idea at all.

Comment: Also, if you stick with the INT strategy, you're talking max values of 21MM ( 21,474,836.47) .  You may be surprised at how fast you'll hit the ceiling.

Comment: (Aside: you're using integer division.  You should divide by `100d`)

Comment: `decimal` is made for exactly this use case - why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would stay away from using integers, because storing the exact number of cents becomes problematic when you need to use fractions of a cent. A need to do so may come up as an intermediate result of a computation, even when you do not intend to store fractional cents.

Unlike `float`s, decimals are perfect for storing monetary amounts. SQL Server also has money data types (`money` and `smallmoney`) which work perfectly fine, too, but require more care while doing math.

Comment: I would not say that `money` and `smallmoney` works "fine too" alongside with `decimal`, for example for large amount of financial operations which include cents in them, you can not even use `SUM()` as you may have difference between real and displayed value, but I agree with the base of your answer, that the best approach because of number of reasons can be just using `decimal(18, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

I would go on using the `decimal`. If you have to calculate fractions, `int / int` will end up as `int`. You'll have to do conversion and use a `decimal` or `double` again.

Comment: I've just tested, dividing `int` by `int` ends up in `int` if you don't convert it explicitly.

Comment: @Irakli Gigiberia: You are right. I changed my answer a bit.